# problems with dropdown nav bar

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm having problems with my navbar. The process of making one is already done, but when I hover over my `nav` and my subnav appears, all the text below it moves down.

How do I fix  this?

Here is a code snippet which demonstrates the problem, hover over `TAKKEN` to see the issue:

```css
.horizontal {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 40 auto;
  width: 640px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.horizontal>li {
  float: left;
}

.horizontal li ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.horizontal li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.horizontal li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid #607987;
  background-color: #006600;
  letter-spacing: .08em;
}

.horizontal li a:hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: #a2becf
}

.horizontal li:first-child a {
  border-left: 0;
}

.horizontal li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="mainnav">
  <ul class="horizontal">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Planning</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Takken</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Kapoenen</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kawellen</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kajoo's</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Jojoo's</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Givers</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Jin</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Akabe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Kleding</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Leiding</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Verhuur</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Inschrijven</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

Here is some text below the nav.
```

[Image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOeMA.jpg)

Comment: Can you atleast post a picture of the problem , maybe a screenshot

Comment: @rilla Please don't add filler text when you see the message that your post has too much code – the message exists for a reason! Instead, try to improve your explanation of the problem, and thank the system for helping you ask a better question. I've suggested an edit which improves your post. Another note: code snippets are really useful to demonstrate issues like this, again, see my edit suggestion.

Comment: @rilla Right, I think we all misunderstood your problem, thinking that it was to do with other `nav` elements moving to the side. The image now clarifies this, I will try to update my answer.

Comment: @rilla I have now updated my answer to be relevant to your image. Run the code snippet to see a demonstration – text under the `nav` no longer moves down, as it did before.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a fixed width to the li elements.

Check this:

```css
.horizontal {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 40 auto;
    width: 640px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.horizontal > li {
    float: left;
    width: 6rem;
}

.horizontal li ul{
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;

}

.horizontal li:hover ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

.horizontal li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 22px 10px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-right: 1px solid #607987;
    background-color: #006600;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
}

.horizontal li a:hover {
    background-color: darkorange; 
    color:#a2becf
}

.horizontal li:first-child a { border-left:0; }
.horizontal li:last-child a { border-right:0; }
```

```html
<nav id="mainnav">
            <ul class="horizontal">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Planning</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Takken</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Kapoenen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Kawellen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Kajoo's</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Jojoo's</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Givers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Jin</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Akabe</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Kleding</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Contact</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Leiding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Verhuur</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Inschrijven</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for commenting on my post! I tried giving my li element a fixed width, but the text is still going down...

Comment: what do you mean by going down? can you explain further?

Comment: i added a picture on the post, my English is not the best

Comment: So i guess @Run_Script gave the answer you required. Clean and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be 2 style-related problems with your `nav`.

1. Elements are being shifted to the side when you hover over `TAKKEN`.

This is happening because the text `KAPOENEN` and `KAWELLEN` is longer and therefore wider than `TAKKEN`. The quickest fix would be to define a specific width for each of the items in your `nav`.

2. Any text below the `nav` moves down as soon as one of the subnavs open.

To solve this problem, you need to give your `nav` an `absolute` position, and add a placeholder `div` to just above it in your HTML.

Run the code snippet below to see a demonstration of both points. I've marked all my changes in the CSS using comments.

```css
/* New code */

#placeholder {
  height: 100px;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

/* End new code */

.horizontal {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 40 auto;
  width: 640px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.horizontal>li {
  float: left;
}

.horizontal li ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.horizontal li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.horizontal li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid #607987;
  background-color: #006600;
  letter-spacing: .08em;
  
  /* New code */
  width: 80px;
}

.horizontal li a:hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: #a2becf
}

.horizontal li:first-child a {
  border-left: 0;
}

.horizontal li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="placeholder"></div>

<nav id="mainnav">
  <ul class="horizontal">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Planning</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Takken</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Kapoenen</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kawellen</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kajoo's</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Jojoo's</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Givers</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Jin</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Akabe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Kleding</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Leiding</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Verhuur</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Inschrijven</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

Here is some text under the nav.
```

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you! Will you accept this answer or do you have any other questions about it?